# WSAGetOverlappedResult doesn't return data from socket

Tags: winsock2, overlapped-io, getoverlappedresult

Here's my code, I'd like to focus on the call to `WSARecv` and `WSAGetOverlappedResult`:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <mswsock.h> // for ACCEPT_CONTEXT

#include <windows.h>

#include <stdio.h> // for wprintf
#include <assert.h>


static char buf[128];
static WSABUF recvBuf = {.len = 128, .buf = buf };


int WINAPI wWinMain(
        HINSTANCE hInstance __attribute__((unused)),
        HINSTANCE hPrevInstance __attribute__((unused)),
        LPWSTR pCmdLine __attribute__((unused)),
        int nCmdShow __attribute__((unused))
    ) {
    WSADATA wsaData = {0};
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        wprintf(L"WSAStartup failed, quitting...\n");
        abort();
    }

    SOCKET listenSock = socket(
        AF_INET,
        SOCK_STREAM,
        IPPROTO_TCP
    );

    if (listenSock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        wprintf(L"Invalid socket, quitting...\n");
        goto cleanupWsa;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in sockAddr = {
        .sin_family = AF_INET,
        .sin_port = htons(8080),
        .sin_addr = INADDR_ANY,
    };

    wchar_t pretty[128];
    DWORD len = sizeof pretty / sizeof(*pretty);
    if (0 != WSAAddressToString(
        (LPSOCKADDR) &sockAddr,
        sizeof sockAddr,
        NULL,
        pretty,
        &len)
    ) {
        wprintf(L"Error during AddressToString, "
            L"check needed address string length %ld, quitting...\n"
            , len);
        goto cleanupSocket;
    }

    wprintf(L"Binding to %ls\n", pretty);

    if (bind(listenSock, (LPSOCKADDR) &sockAddr, sizeof sockAddr)
        == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"Bind error, quitting...\n");
        goto cleanupSocket;
    }


    if (listen(listenSock, SOMAXCONN) != 0) {
        wprintf(L"Listen error, quitting...\n");
        goto cleanupSocket;
    }


    struct sockaddr s;
    int socklen = sizeof s;
    SOCKET acceptSocket = accept(listenSock, &s, &socklen);

    wprintf(L"ACCEPT\n");

    if (SOCKET_ERROR == setsockopt(
        acceptSocket,
        SOL_SOCKET,
        SO_UPDATE_ACCEPT_CONTEXT,
        (char *)&listenSock,
        sizeof listenSock
    )) {
        wprintf(L"setsockopt update_accept_context failure\n");
        goto cleanupBothSockets;
    }
    DWORD flags = WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED;

    WSAOVERLAPPED w;
    memset(&w, 0, sizeof w);
    if (WSARecv(
        acceptSocket,
        &recvBuf,
        1,//dwBufferCount 
        NULL,//lpBytesReceived 
        &flags,
        &w,
        NULL
    ) != SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"Recv: expected SOCKET_ERROR\n");
        goto cleanupBothSockets;
    }
    int errnr = WSAGetLastError();
    if (errnr != WSA_IO_PENDING) {
        wprintf(L"RecvErr %d\n", errnr);
        goto cleanupBothSockets;
    }

    wprintf(L"Running GetOverlappedResult\n");
    DWORD bytes_transferred;
    BOOL ret = WSAGetOverlappedResult(acceptSocket, &w, &bytes_transferred, TRUE, &flags);
    if (ret == FALSE) {
        wprintf(L"OverlappedResult: error\n");
    } else {
        wprintf(L"OverlappedResult: finished with no error, bytes transferred %d", bytes_transferred);
    }

cleanupBothSockets:
    closesocket(acceptSocket);
cleanupSocket:
    closesocket(listenSock);
cleanupWsa:
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, it listens for a connection. I connect with netcat. After connecting, it prints 'ACCEPT', as expected. It also prints 'Running GetOverlappedResult', but even though I write lots of gibberish on the netcat, neither of the "OverlappedResult:" lines appear, until I push Control-C on the netcat, and the connection dies. Then, I hit the success branch, and it says that 0 bytes were transferred.

What is wrong with this program? Why doesn't `WSAGetOverlappedResult` return as soon as the 128 byte buffer is filled?

I scrutinized my calls to `WSARecv` and `WSAGetOverlappedResult`. Here are some details:

- I set the socket for `WSARecv` to `acceptSocket`, since I want to read from the concrete connection that was established.
- I set the buffer count to one because I just have a single buffer, and C doesn't distinguish in memory between an array with one element, and just an element. So I can use the `recvBuf` as a one-sized array.
- I set `lpNumberOfBytesRecvd` to null, since MSDN tells me to do that if I supply `lpOverlapped`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` to `WSARecv`. The socket itself is already either overlapped or not. If you pass `0` instead, the program notices the bytes from `netcat`.

Furthermore, you cannot assume that `WSARecv` will always generate the error `ERROR_IO_PENDING`. The data may be available right away, in which case it will just return `0`. So you need to handle both these cases as success.

If you make the request with e.g. `curl`, the data may be available right away, and the program will complain that it didn't get `ERROR_IO_PENDING`, which you get when you manually type stuff into the socket with `netcat`.